# DPMS config in kiosk mode with xorg and openbox

Tags: xorg, kiosk

I just put together a raspberry PI in kiosk mode that is using xorg and openbox to auto launch the chromium browser in kiosk mode.  It's using xorg and openbox to display the browser, and works fine, however I would like to tweak the DPMS.

I can add the following to /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart and it will blank the screen after 2 minutes

`xset dpms 0 0 120`

And when I tap the touchscreen it comes back on, however I can still see that the screen is backlit and drawing power, is there a way to completely turnoff the screen and power it back on after X minutes while allowing it to come back on after touching the screen?

Also, is there a way to disable the mouse click that results from the 1st tap after it blanks/powers off?  With the above config it works, but when I tap the blank screen anywhere there is a link, it clicks the link, I'd like the first screen tap after blanking/powering off to just wake it up, not actually click anything.

Answer (score 0):

/boot/config.txt

add: hdmi_blanking=1

That did it, but now my screen is displaying "No signal" which is a hardware issue with the display.  Will research that one seperately.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.